# not able to access $_POST variables in file + select tag form send

Tags: php, html

Form Code :

```
<form action="my_php.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="postfile">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="style1">
</form>
```

Select Tag :

```
<select id="lang" form="postfile">
    <option value="gcc">C</option>
    <option value="g++">C++</option>
    <option value="javac">Java</option>
    <option value="python">Python</option>
</select>
```

I am not able to access the `$_POST["lang"]` from the PHP Code.When i do:

```
echo $_POST["lang"];
```

It doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you got to have the `name="lang"` attribute on your `<select>` tag:

```
<select id="lang" form="postfile" name="lang">
                                    ^ this
```

Reminder: Always access `$_POST` values, **after** the submission so you don't have to deal with undefined indices.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // then access your POST values
    $lang = $_POST['lang'];
}

// this assumes you have an <input type="submit" name="submit" /> button
```

Comment: @PRP sure glad this shed light